# annoying Xcode autocompletion @string and @selector?

Tags: ios, xcode, autocomplete, nsstring, selector

Lets say you go to enter in a parameter and it's a string, so you go `@` and with a press of the `return key` Xcode fills the template of a string for you `@"String"`. This is the "first option" on the popup suggestions.

Next you want to enter in a `@selector` for a `performSelector:` method, when you type in `@`
the default is a string so you have to go `down` on your keypad, that's okay.

The next time you want to enter in a string, the default is `@selector` now when you hit the `return key` after typing `@`

I know I am being a little bit pedantic but as the quote goes:

> The three chief virtues of a programmer are: Laziness, Impatience and Hubris.

So to my question is there a way to always make the `@string` "default" or an even quicker shortcut other than `@"`?

ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what XCode does is , in the suggestion box,what ever you selected the last time it comes selected now.What you selected now has more chance of using it next time, so xcode suggest the same the next time. I don't think you can set something as default.